# assign value to private attribute from subclass

Tags: java, subclass

So i have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Superclass {
    private final boolean isTrue;
    private final int number1;
    private final int number2;
    private final int number3;

    public Superclass(boolean isTrue, int number1, int number2, int number3) {
        this.isTrue = isTrue;
        this.number1 = Math.abs(number1);
        this.number2 = Math.abs(number2);
        this.number3 = Math.abs(number3);
    }
```

On top of that i created a subclass of "Superclass" which is supposed to have 2 public constructors:

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass{

    public Subclass(int number2, int number3) {
     ...
    }

    public Subclass(int number1, int number2, int number3) {
     ...
    }
```

Now i want to assign "isTrue" true or false in those constructors, depending on the values of the numbers. e.g. if "number2" and "number3" > 0, i want to assign false to "isTrue". Is there a way to make this work without having to change "isTrue" to public/protected? Thanks you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the existing constructor to solve this.

For the case number2 and number3 > 0, you can do this:

```
public Subclass(int number2, int number3) {
   super(!(number2 > 0 && number3 > 0), 0, number2, number3);
}
```

Similar changes can be made to the other constructor.

Comment: I suggest writing `number2 <= 0 || number3 <= 0` to avoid the `!` and the brackets.

Comment: Thank you @kaya3. yes, we can do that as well. I wasn't sure of additional requirements such as number2 is 0 and number3 > 0 etc... so just answered only for the given condition.

Answer (score 1):

Child can access parent's constructor using the super() method. To simplify what @Sunil suggested,

```
public Subclass(int number1, int number2, int number3) {
  super(checkCondition(number2, number3), number1, number2, number3)
}
```

And in checkCondition you can mention all the necessary and complex conditions

```
private checkCondition(int a, int b){
  return !(a>0 && b>0);
}
```